# How do I use all four cameras of the iPhone 12 in WhatsApp?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app, video-conference

The iPhone 12 has four cameras; the front camera, a general use one on the back, a wide angle one and a zoom camera.

During video chats placed with the WhatsApp app, only the front camera and the general use one of the back can be accessed.
It is therefore very difficult to show certain things during a call that would require the wide angle or zoom cameras.

Can I use choose which of the 4 cameras of the iPhone 12 WhatsApp will use to share in a call?

Comment: To clarify: Do you wish to use all the cameras _at the same time_ or rather be able to _cycle_  through them (one at a time)?

Comment: @NicApicella to cycle through them!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a limitation of WhatsApp. On Android, there was a workaround of switching between front and back cameras, and that would cycle between rear cameras, but even that was removed earlier this year.

Facetime has a workaround to zoom using this method, which may switch the camera being used: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/secret-facetime-trick-lets-you-zoom-with-your-iphones-camera-0318068/

> While engaged in a FaceTime call, switch to the rear camera by tapping the "flip" button. Now, double-tap your video feed to expand it. Your feed will become larger, hiding other video feeds from view. From here, just pinch out to zoom the feed like you would in the Camera app. If the trick is working correctly, you should see your video zoom in. Of course, pinching in reverse (pinching in) zooms back out.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/328313)

Comment: Thank you, I updated the answer with the relevant info from the link.